# How is the number of successful packets through a network calculated based on the probability of a successful transmission?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Trying to intuitively understand this:

If I have $N$ packets flowing through a network, and the probability of a packet being successfully transmitted is $p$, how is the total number of packets that successfully went through $S$ equal $Np$ ?

The reason I have trouble understanding this is, assume $p=10\%$. If I send $10$ packets through a network, it doesn't necessarily mean I get only $Np=10×10\%=1$ packet to transmit successfully right? Couldn't I potentially get more than one packet to successfully transmit?

I came across this reasoning from [Computer Networks 5th edition](https://csc-knu.github.io/sys-prog/books/Andrew%20S.%20Tanenbaum%20-%20Computer%20Networks.pdf).
Here's an excerpt from the book:

> Under all loads, the throughput, $S$, is just the offered
> load, $G$, times the probability, $P_0$, of a transmission succeeding—that is, $S=GP_0$, where $P_0$ is the probability that a frame does not suffer a collision.

Comment: On average you will get 1 per time period with 10% transmission rate. Of course, in any one time period you might get 0 or more than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're carrying out $N$  transmissions, each of which is a [bernoulli trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) with success probability of $p$,
the distribution of number of successful transmissions is
the [binomial $(N, p)$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

The "expected value" (i.e. the average) of this distribution is $Np$, which is what the textbook claims.

Answer (score 2):

"Expected" is implied before "throughput" here – and I don't think this is a justified elision. There may be $2$ or $0$ or even $10$ packets that went through in a transmission of $10$ packets with $p=10\%$, but in the long run you would expect $1$ in $10$ packets to go through.